# Set height of a specific cell in my UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two cells (one dynamic and other static) and I want to set different height for each cell like:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       /*tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
       tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)
      if cell1 return 100
      if cell2 return 20  */
    }
```

It's possible to specific height for each cell not row.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For static cell (created either as Xib or in storyboard), you can set the height like this, if you are displaying static cell in first row of your Table View.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    return 120
}

return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

}

To populate the static cell along with dynamic cell, You should do,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datasource.count + 1
```

}

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewAutomaticDimension

https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells -

If you set correctly the autolayout for the cell you can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to have the size without have to specify.

Comment: If you still want to redefine manually you have to map the cell by the indexPath.row and indexPath.section. You must know for exaxmple for row 2 the type it will be since at this point the cell are not yet initialized.

Comment: you got the point, I dunno why everyone here gets the specific row instead of using some generic approach

Answer (score 1):

***In, Swift 3.0**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   if indexPath.row == 0 {

         return 100
   } else {

         return 200
   }

}
```

or you can set Constraint of your Cell proper and then write this code of your **`ViewDidLoad`** Method

```
yourTblView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

yourTblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension*
```

Comment: thanks @Jaydip but not working for me because i have 2 cell one dynamic and other static i want to know if it possible to specific cell not row

Comment: son your case you can try array of dictionary and set key cell_Type and set.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to return a height for each indexPath. There is no need to dequeue a cell here. If you want different prototype cells you will do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You can specify as many sections and rows as you want:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      switch indexPath.section {
      case 0:
          switch indexPath.row {
          case 0:
              return 100.0
          case 1:
              return 20.0
          // Add rows here if needed
          default:
              return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      // Add sections here if needed
      default:
          default:
              return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      }
}
```

Comment: you don't use it. It will be called with the rest of functions from the delegate every time you call `tableView.reloadData()` for example

Comment: Check that your cell reuse identifiers match and that all your IBOutlets are connected properly

Comment: did you manage to get it working @Akram? If so, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
          return 100
      } else {
          return 20
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichałKwiecień, I have already tried, it work but first cell not appear